# Can't restart apache2

Tags: virtualbox, apache2, php, reboot, sql

I already work on Apache2 so IDK where does this problem comes from.
If I type "sudo systemctl retsart apache2" I got "Job for apache2 failed because the control process exited with error code".
I work on a VirtualBox.
I tried so many things that I can't remember all of them and I begin to get desesperate. I have a project for school and I really need to be able to retsart Apache2 but I won't see my professor until we submit it.

(I'm french so if my english isn't understandable tell me)

Comment: `service apache2 status` will help you find which of your recent `apache2` changes confused `apache2`.

Comment: "I tried so many things that I can't remember all of them" is the Very Worst Way of managing your system. When one of the "things" failed, did you revert the changes it made to your system, or did you build a tower of failed system changes on failed system changes?

Comment: Building a new Ubuntu VM with Apache and a database engine shouldn’t take more than 30 minutes in many cases. Perhaps it’s best to just make a new VM and copy your files over? Be sure to document your changes to the system going forward 